# Threaded repaint opening new window

Tags: java, multithreading, window, awt, repaint

I am using java to make a simple game. I have code that forty times a second, runs the screen thread. However, whenever i call the screen thread a new window opens up and the old one also stays open. Is there a way I can fix this? Thanks

```
package sylvyrfysh;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import sylvyrfysh.handlers.OreHandler;
import sylvyrfysh.troops.manager.TroopManager;

public class Screen extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -377919050238217712L;
    public Screen(){
        super("Commander");
        setContentPane(new DrawPane());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));
        setSize(607,669);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        KeyboardFocusManager manager=KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new EventHandler());
        addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
    }
    class DrawPane extends JPanel{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2729138328693556841L;
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0,0,600,40);
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.drawString("Ore: "+Main.ore,0,10);
            g.drawString("Base Health: "+Main.baseHealth,0,30);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(0,40,600,600);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(0,40,100,100);
            for(int[] i:TroopManager.troops){
                g.fillRect(i[1],i[2]+40,1,1);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(500, 540, 100, 100);
            for(int[] i:TroopManager.enemyTroops){
                g.fillRect(i[1],i[2]+40,1,1);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            for(int[] i:OreHandler.ore){
                g.fillRect(i[1],i[2]+40,1,1);
            }
        }
    }
    public void run(){repaint();}
}
```

EDIT: What appears to be happening is whenever i call the screen thread, it also calls the constructor.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Once that code is changed to be compilable and runnable, I see only one frame.

Comment: What does "call the screen thread" mean? It would be helpful if you posted the code that does this.

Comment: @StuartMarks  And then we can look forward to dribs-and-drabs of code snippets the OP thinks might be relevant.  Tip: someone that can't solve the problem is hardly likely to know which part of the codes are relevant.  An SSCCE ***guarantees*** the relevant code is present.

Comment: Fair enough; an SSCCE would be ideal. Assuming the OP can produce one....

Comment: `public void run(){repaint();}` you don't want to be calling `repaint()` 40 time a second to repaint the frame. what you need is [active rendering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html)

Comment: Let me guess, you call the screen by using something like new Thread(new Screen()); ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah. I used (new Thread(new Screen())).start(); which called a new screen every time it ran.

Comment: There's your problem.  Each time you call `new Screen`, you are creating a brand new instance of `Screen`, which is call it's constructor, which is creating a new window...